# Do DC generators require more maintenance than AC generators?

Tags: electrical, generator

Whilst researching, I found several sites that suggested DC generators required much more maintenance than AC generators. From what I can tell these sites seem to have assumed that the AC generator was brushless while the DC generator had brushes. So it would make sense that the DC generator would require more servicing in this scenario.

However, I'm still wondering if there is any truth to this, is there some other factor that results in DC generators having a shorter lifespan than AC generators?

*The sites in question:*

- [site 1](https://www.reactivegenerators.com.au/blog/what-is-the-difference-between-ac-and-dc-industrial-generators/#:%7E:text=The%20absences%20of%20brushes)
- [site 2](https://karatec.com.au/ac-generator-motors/#:%7E:text=Longer%20lifespan%20compared%20to%20DC%20motors)
- [site 3](https://byjus.com/physics/difference-between-ac-and-dc-generator/#:%7E:text=AC%20generators%20require%20very%20little)

Answer (score -1):

After discussing the topic with my teacher, I believe I've come to a conclusion.

DC generators not only require the generating of the DC current, but they will generally also be converting it to a flatlined DC current rather than a fluctuating one.
So it stands to reason that there is far more opportunity for components to become damaged, therefore meaning that DC generators do indeed require more maintenance than their AC counterpart.